# SignalR: How do I dynamically register a Hub?

Tags: asp.net, .net, signalr

I'm creating a .NET library that has a SignalR hub inside of it. The programmer will import my library inside his/her ASP.NET web application and I need my hub to be available.

Normally people would register hubs using `IAppBuilder.MapSignalR` but it apparently doesn't work with hubs from different assemblies.

How do I do this? I can't find anything related in the SignalR documentation.